# Allow WRITE_SETTINGS permission with Android 11 from manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-11

I have an application that is meant for "locked Android phones" meaning the application is the only application users will have access to on that phone and that is done using MySync.

Before the application had to support Android 11 (complieSdkVersion 30), the user was able to change screen brightness and other system settings from the application (Since the user did not have access to the settings app). But now the `WRITE_SETTINGS` and `CHANGE_CONFIGURATION` are deprecated and no longer have desirable effects.

I am aware that it is possible to prompt the user to accept the settings with this prompt:

```
    boolean permission;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        permission = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
    } else {
        permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
    if (permission) {
        initApp();
    }  else {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
            startActivityForResult(intent, SettingsActivity.CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS}, SettingsActivity.CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
```

But since the user does not have access to the settings application in my app eco-system, I can not give the user a prompt that would open up the settings and allow the user to stay in the settings.

Is there no way around this permission request and is there no way to do it on the manifest level or some other way?